# Run Time Error 1004: Method 'Save As' Fail_of object' Workbook' Failed

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code results in a "SaveAs" error. I have not been able to figure it out. Just trying to change xlsb files into xls files. I have read most of the suggestions in the snawer query but none of the seem to work.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveAsXLS()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim nameWB As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then Exit Sub

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xlsb*"

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
Call DetermineNonBuiltinCommandBars
nameWB = Replace(myFile, ".xlsb", "")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nameWB, FileFormat:=xls <---- ERROR
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

myFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. The parameter `FileFormat:=xls` is failing because `xls` is an undeclared variable. It should be a member of the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel).

Comment: That did not work. I will edit the code I posted to reflect the change I made based on your comment.  Note adding option Explicit forced me to declare "nameWB" As String, as it was previously undeclared.

Comment: That's because you still have `FileFormat:=xls`. It has to be an `XlFileFormat`. If you have `xls` declared somewhere and it isn't a member of that enumeration, it's wrong. I think you mean `FileFormat:=xlExcel8`, but it's hard to tell which one you need. You have to *pick one from the list*.

Comment: Curious: I wrote 'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nameWB, FileFormat:=56' and it now runs without error but I do not see any changes to the file ?

Comment: I think you also need to replace xlsb in nameWB with "xls" so that the file has the correct extension?

Comment: @CindyMeister if you answerize that I will accept the answer and throw some points your way. That worked.